# only accept certain ip/mac/ethtype packets in a socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, filtering, packet

I;m a completely new in network programming and a starter in python.

I want so set a socket in Python to just accept certain packages.
I have the following values at my disposal:

destination address and port
source MAC address
ethtype (own)

how can I set a filter to my socket class to only accept packets for me (at dest address,port)
and/or the right ethtype, and/or send by the device with the known mac address ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I tried to look via Google, but the amount of hits is incredible, and I haven't been able to find an answer that solves my question so far.

Thanx,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It is a great tool for crafting custom packets and to do lot of other stuff.

You can add [filters](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#filters) in the scapy's [sniff()](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing) to capture the packets you desire. You can also use scapy with your own python programm.
More over you'll find ton of tutorials on the internet on how to use scapy.